# jQuery spinner and Knockout

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, data-binding, knockout.js, spinner

How can I combine a jQuery UI spinner widget with Knockout? This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12929801/jqueryui-spinner-widget-with-knockout) no longer works because there is no `spinchange` event. This is my HTML:

```
<input id='spinner' data-bind='value:theValue' />
<span data-bind='text:theValue'></span>
```

And my JS:

```
$(function() {
    $('#spinner').spinner();

    var viewModel = {
        theValue: ko.observable(3)
    };

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
```

You can play around with this in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/petermorlion/H8v23/). As you can see, using the spinner buttons won't change the text inside the `span`. Entering a number with your keyboard and then putting the focus elsewhere on the page will change the text (so the binding works).

Because I'm using ASP.NET, and have this spinner widget wrapped up in a `WebControl`, it might have something to do with that. I can't take the same approach as in aforementioned answer, because we're not using Knockout on every page.

But if I could even get the jsFiddle to work, that would probably help me further, or even just be the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ahem, no need to look any further. Apparently, the answer was just about right. The problem was with the `ko.utils.registerEventHandler` I believe. It works when I changed the code to:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.spinnerValue = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        //handle the field changing
        $(element).on('spinstop', function () {
            var observable = valueAccessor();
            observable($(element).spinner("value"));
        });
    },

    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());

        current = $(element).spinner("value");
        if (value !== current) {
            $(element).spinner("value", value);
        }
    }
};
```

So I use jQuery and the `on` function. The `spinstop` event does exist (as does `spinchange`). I had been looking in the code and just searching for the string. I guess the jQuery code does it a little different.

Anyway, this custom handler works, even with our ASP.NET WebControl. With older versions of the spinner (we were using 1.20 before), the normal KO databinding worked.