# Using KnockoutJS with jQuery UI Spinner

Tags: ajax, data-binding, knockout.js, durandal

I am using jQuery UI's spinner with KnockoutJS and Durandal right now. I followed the answer/example
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12929801/jqueryui-spinner-widget-with-knockout) to create a custom binding that takes care of initializing the spinner and of observing the changes made to the spinner.

Now, I have saved that as a common module to be loaded in a *lib* folder, invoked by whichever modules that need to use spinners in the future. My problem here is I want to, on this particular page, to retrieve the value of the spinner/<input> to make an ajax call each time the spinner and thus the quantity is updated. I know I can't possibly be putting my custom ajax code in the common module, but I have no idea where to put it.

Here's the HTML that's doing the data binding:

```
<p class="qty">
    <input class="spinner" data-bind="spinner: quantity, spinnerOptions: { min: 1, numberFormat: 'n' }" />
    <a class="remove" href="#">Remove</a>
</p>
```

And this is the code that corresponds to the HTML:

```
function Item(data) {
    (...)
    self.updateQuantity = function(){
    $.ajax(apiUrl + self.id, {
        data: self.quantity,
        type: 'patch',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function(result) {
            alert(result);
        }
        });
    };
}

(...)

     return {
    checkedOutItems: checkedOutItems, //checkedoutItems is an array of Item that's passed to the HTML, which can call Item's updateQuantity method
(...)
}
```

Here's the common module I've built based on the link above:

```
define(function(require) {

    var system = require('durandal/system'),
    app = require('durandal/app'),
    ko = require('knockout');

    ko.bindingHandlers.spinner = {

    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {

        //initialize datepicker with some optional options
            var options = allBindingsAccessor().spinnerOptions || {};
            $(element).spinner(options);

            //handle the field changing
            ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, 'spinchange', function () {
        var observable = valueAccessor();
        observable($(element).spinner('value'));
            });

            //handle disposal (if KO removes by the template binding)
            ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function() {
        $(element).spinner('destroy');
            });

    },

    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
            var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()),
        current = $(element).spinner('value'),
        msg = 'You have entered an Invalid Quantity. \n Please enter at least 1 or remove this item if you do not want to include it in the shopping cart.';

        system.log(value);

        if(isNaN(parseInt(value))) {
        alert(msg);
        }

            if (value !== current && !isNaN(parseInt(value))) {
        $(element).spinner("value", value);
            }
    }
    };

});
```

As far as I know, I should have something like `data-bind="value: quantity, click: updateQuantity"` to call the updateQuantity function as soon as the observable quantity changes. However, now that I'm using the *spinner* custom binding, I'm no longer sure how to call the updateQuantity function anymore. Each change will be captured by the code in the common module (as the system.log shows in Chrome inspector), but in my page.js, I don't know where and how to call the function that captures the new quantity to be used in the ajax call.

I realize my understanding of KnockoutJS and data binding is still fuzzy (just started few weeks ago), so I will be most glad if someone would enlighten me as to where I should go from here. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps, but if you can get access to the ViewModel's binding context from within the update callback function of the custom spinner binding, and the `updateQuantity()` function is inside the ViewModel, then I see no reason why you wouldn't be able to call `updateQuantity()` [from within the update callback](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making your AJAX call and your spinner have nothing to do with each other.  Below, I show you how we did this, but using SpinJS.  The principal is the same despite the fact that the library is different.

Here's our custom binding for the spinner:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.spinner = {
            init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
                var options = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());

                var opts = {
                    lines: options .lines || 8,
                    length: options .length || 3,
                    width: options .width || 4,
                    radius: options .radius || 6,
                    color: options .color || '#FFF',
                    speed: options .speed || 1,
                    trail: options .trail || 100,
                    shadow: options .shadow == undefined ? false : value.shadow,
                    zIndex: options .zIndex || 2000
                };

                var spinner = new Spinner(opts).stop();
                $(element).data(element.id, spinner);
            },

            update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
                var options = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()),

                    isSpinning = options .isSpinning,
                    positioning = options .positioning || 'manual',

                    spinner = $(element).data(element.id);

                if (isSpinning) {
                    if (positioning == 'manual') {
                        spinner.spin();
                        $(element)[0].appendChild(spinner.el);
                    } else if (positioning == 'auto') {
                        spinner.spin(element);
                    }
                } else {
                    spinner.stop();
                }
            }
```

Here's a view where the custom binding is being used:

```
<div data-bind="visible: isFetchingOpportunities()">
    <div id="activitySpinner" class="ts-ajax-spinner" data-bind="spinner: { isSpinning: isFetchingOpportunities() }">
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the corresponding viewModel that backs the view above:

```
this.isFetchingOpportunities(true);
var that = this;
$.when(dataservice.getData(options, getFunction, modelmapper.opportunity))
     .then(function() {
         that.isFetchingOpportunities(false);
     });
```

Now, we've wrapped up our AJAX calls into a data service that, in turn, leverages AmplifyJS.  But, again, the principal is the same.  You could just as easily make your AJAX calls directly.

Does this make sense?

Comment: Thanks for your help. Using isSpinning as an option to be checked in the custom binding is interesting. I couldn't really get your second part though, what with the when, then, and that. I ended up using `<input class="spinner" data-bind="spinner: quantity, spinnerOptions: { min: 1, numberFormat: 'n' }, callbackFunction: callbackOnUpdate" />` to invoke a callback via allBindings.

Comment: You're welcome.  Yes, our `dataservice` returns a promise that gets resolved when the AJAX call (out to our REST API) comes back.  That's what triggers the `then`.  In other words, the spinner spins until the AJAX call resolves, at which point the spinning is set to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, I think all you need to do is subscribe to the quantity observable and make your ajax call with in that function. something like :-

Note: I changed the `ko.utils.registerEventHandler` from `spinchange` to `spinstop`

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.spinner = {

  init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {

    //initialize datepicker with some optional options
    var options = allBindingsAccessor().spinnerOptions || {};
    $(element).spinner(options);

    //handle the field changing
    ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, 'spinstop', function() {
      var observable = valueAccessor();
      observable($(element).spinner('value'));
    });

    //handle disposal (if KO removes by the template binding)
    ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function() {
      $(element).spinner('destroy');
    });

  },

  update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()),
      current = $(element).spinner('value'),
      msg = 'You have entered an Invalid Quantity. \n Please enter at least 1 or remove this item if you do not want to include it in the shopping cart.';



    if (isNaN(parseInt(value))) {
      alert(msg);
    }

    if (value !== current && !isNaN(parseInt(value))) {
      $(element).spinner("value", value);
    }
  }
};

var Vm = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.quantity = ko.observable(0);

  self.quantity.subscribe(updateData);


  function updateData(newValue) {
    //do ajax call here
    alert(newValue);
  }


  return self;
};

ko.applyBindings(new Vm());
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>


<p class="qty">
  <input class="spinner" data-bind="spinner: quantity, spinnerOptions: { min: 1, numberFormat: 'n' }" />
  <a class="remove" href="#">Remove</a>
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Subscribe looks like an interesting function to use - I didn't use it this time, but it could come in handy in the future.